# Unable to debug 64-bit application in release configuration, with Debug information enabled

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe6

I am trying to debug an application that is in **Release Configuration - 64-bit Windows platform**, but no breakpoints will hit.

I have enabled the Compiler **Debug Information** option:

[image]

I *can* debug the application when it is in the **32-bit** release configuration; the breakpoints work fine.

```
| Configuration | 32-bit     | 64-bit     |
|---------------|------------|------------|
| Debug         | Debuggable | Debuggable |
| Release       | Debuggable | Fails      |

All with "Debug information" set to "Debug information", 
and full build (Shift+F9) before running.
```

So three questions:

- why does setting **Debug information** work for the 32-bit debugger, but not the 64-bit dubugger?
- why is the 64-bit debugger able to debug an application in **Debug** configuration, but not in **Release** configuration?
- what option do i change to let me debug 64-bit applications in the **Release** configuration?

## Bonus Screenshots

32-bit release linker options:

[image]

64-bit release linker options:

[image]

Comment: This should work (I do this with my project) but the 64 bit debugger is a tad flaky. Have you tried on a vanilla project?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good suggestion; i hadn't tried a fresh project. Still fails. So it should just be chalked up to Embarcadero commitment to quality? It really is strange that there's some secret communication between the IDE and the debugger that disables debugging.

Comment: @JerryDodge [You are going to pay for bug fixes. And you’re going to like it!](http://www.codingindelphi.com/blog/you-are-going-to-pay-for-bug-fixes-and-youre-going-to-like-it/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to enable **debug information** in the linker options. At least, when I disable that, breakpoints are not hit, and when I enable that setting, breakpoints are hit.

In summary, from what I can tell by using the trusted technique of trial-and-error, you need the following to enable debugging:

- 32 bit: compiler debug information enabled.
- 64 bit: compiler and linker debug information enabled.

Comment: Trial-and-error is the best kind of error! It, confusingly, works. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, i take it back. It's 32-bit release that (still) works with linker debug information enabled. But i think we'll simply say *"it's another bug in the product"* - and don't try to develop 64-bit applications in Delphi. \*sigh\*

Comment: I don't understand that comment, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I have a project that links to 6 of my own packages and have moved to 64bit.  All debugs fine in win32 but wouldn't stop at breakpoints in win64.

I found the paths to the dcp files were required in the project\search path and that it could not be RELATIVE!
It works fine with variables such as C:\dcp$(Platform)$(Config) but not with ..\Dcp$(Platform)$(Config)

I believe the problem is the win32 debugging happens 'in house' but as the ide is not 64 bit debugging must occur outside (as remote debugging must be enabled for 64 bit) and the remote debugger's starting directory is not the same therefore the relative path would be relative to some other location.

I also enabled map files but don't think that made a difference because with the relative path nothing worked.

Sorry for answering a really old question but after going mad for a whole day I just had to tell someone and am sure I will have to google for this answer in the future when I forget as I am a fan of relative paths.